# Is there a way of using isin() as calculator function for another column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column as 'PRODUCT_ID' in my pandas dataframe. I want to create a calculated column based on this column that PRODUCT_IDs in [3, 5, 8] will be taking value 'old' and others 'new'.

Right now I'm using a for loop to check every single index of the dataframe.

```
portfoy['PRODUCT_TYPE'] = np.nan

for ind in portfoy.index:
    if portfoy.loc[ind, 'PRODUCT_CODE'] in [3, 5, 8]:
        portfoy.loc[ind, 'PRODUCT_TYPE'] = 'old'
    else:
        portfoy.loc[ind, 'PRODUCT_TYPE'] = 'new'
```

This code seems to take a lot of time. Is there a better way to do this?

My data looks like:

| CUSTOMER | PRODUCT_ID | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2345 | 3 | ------------- |
| 3456 | 5 | ------------- |
| 2786 | 5 | ------------- |

Comment: could you add some sample data so we know roughly what your dataframe looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for vectorized fast solution:

```
portfoy['PRODUCT_TYPE'] = np.where(portfoy['PRODUCT_CODE'].isin([3, 5, 8]), 'old', 'new')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use masks to conditional update the data frame

```
portfoy.loc[portfoy.PRODUCT_CODE.isin([3,5,8]),'PRODUCT_TYPE'] = 'old'

portfoy.loc[~portfoy.PRODUCT_CODE.isin([3,5,8]),'PRODUCT_TYPE'] = 'new'
```

portfoy.PRODUCT_CODE.isin([3,5,8] is the mask
~ is the negation of the mask